# sitecore, error updating index - LockRecursionException

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I'm getting the following error when updating the index for a single item.  I don't have a clue where to start.  My instinct is the fully rebuild the index, but this likely would generate the same error again?

```
anagedPoolThread #79 15:22:51 INFO  Starting update of index for the database 'master' (3 pending).
ManagedPoolThread #60 15:22:51 INFO  Starting update of index for the database 'web' (3 pending).
ManagedPoolThread #60 15:22:51 ERROR Could not update index entry. Action: 'Saved', Item: '{2845828F-1CBC-4F6B-AFC5-8558E8C472A0}'
Exception: System.Threading.LockRecursionException
Message: Recursive read lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode.
Source: System.Core
  at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterReadLockCore(TimeoutTracker timeout)
  at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterReadLock(TimeoutTracker timeout)
  at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterReadLock(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
  at Sitecore.Search.IndexDeleteContext..ctor(ILuceneIndex index)
  at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.DeleteItem(Item item)
  at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.UpdateItem(Item item)
  at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  at Sitecore.Data.Managers.IndexingProvider.UpdateItem(HistoryEntry entry, Database database)
  at Sitecore.Data.Managers.IndexingProvider.UpdateIndex(HistoryEntry entry, Database database)
```

Comment: Could you check if the version on the item that you are trying to update/delete exists?

Comment: it was.  I just reindexed everything and we're good

Comment: I'm having the same issue, even after rebuilding all indexes. Any ideas? The items in question are all system/tasks/schedules

Comment: yeah, my issues came back... still there